# Extract a number with sed

Tags: regex, sed

Given

`<span class="results"><strong>1</strong>  = <strong>1.093691</strong> </span>`

how can I extract just `1.093691` with `sed`?

`[\d\.]{2,}` will *match* the number, but how do I do the opposite, i.e., get rid of everything else?

I tried using `^` but couldn't figure it out.

Maybe `awk`?

Comment: BTW Correct regex for matching that number is `\d+\.\d+`

Comment: Do you _need_ to use sed?  This looks like XML, so a standard XML parser is the tool for the job (e.g. using an XPath query).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this grep line works for your example input:

```
grep -oP '[\d.]+(?=</strong>\s*</span>$)'
```

or sed works for your given example too.

```
sed  's/.*<strong>//;s#</strong>.*##'
```

same idea with gnu awk:

```
awk -F'</?strong>' '{$0=$(NF-1)}7'
```

Comment: @Ze'ev you didn't say a word about which version of sed/awk you have, I thought the gnu ones.  I added a sed one-liner, should go with bsd-sed too. give it a shot

Comment: Your `sed` example works ... though I have no idea how! Gonna have to look that up.

Comment: @Ze'ev added an awk one-liner

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

`sed -E 's:.*<strong>([0-9.]+).*:\1:g'`